# how to get both value @RequestBody and @RequestParam together

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

how to get both values @RequestBody and @RequestParam together??
below the code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/sign-up", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody User user,@RequestParam("location") String location,@RequestParam("deviceid") String deviceid) {  

    System.out.println(location);

    System.out.println(deviceid);
```

it is possible?
for `@RequestParam` Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
and for `@RequestBody` Content-type application/json
i want both value location and deviceid if there is any other way?

Comment: A request can't have several content types. Unless you post multiple parts as part of a multipart/form-data request. Otherwise, you question doesn't make much sense. If you pst JSON already, why don't you post a JSON object containing the user, the location and the deviceId?

Comment: thanks for reply ..USER not content location and deviceid ..\

Comment: i want to get  location and deviceid from client in Striing

Comment: is there way any to get separate @RequestParam from client

Comment: And JSON objects can contain string values. So, store these string values in a JSON object, and send that JSON as the body of the request

Answer (score 0):

1. @PathVariable is to obtain some placeholder from the uri (Spring
   call it an URI Template) — see  [Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.2.2 URI](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) 
   Template Patterns
2. @RequestParam is to obtain an parameter — see  [Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.3.3 Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

If URL `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/user/1234/invoices?date=12-05-2013` gets the invoices for user 1234 on December 5th, 2013, the controller method would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}/invoices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Invoice> listUsersInvoices(
            @PathVariable("userId") int user,
            @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date dateOrNull) {
  ...
}
```

Also, request parameters can be optional, but path variables cannot--if they were, it would change the URL path hierarchy and introduce request mapping conflicts. For example, would /user/invoices provide the invoices for user null or details about a user with ID "invoices"